# Highchart - spider web chart - chart appears and part of the chart disappears

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highchart and its spider web chart.

Everything loads fine and then after about a second, part of the line disappears.[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo, i.e on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of highcharts and hichgharts-more fixed this problem.